# Always keep same vertical distance between two divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my Markup:

```
 <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
 <h1 class="text-info">Headline One</h1><hr>
 <button>Show More</button>
 </div>

 <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
 <h1 class="text-info">Headline Two</h1><hr>
 <button>Show More</button>
 </div>

 <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
 <h1 class="text-info">Headline Three</h1><hr>
 <button>Show More</button>
 </div>
```

First div is on left, second to its right and third one below first. Now, if I click on show more in the second div, there is a lot of blank space between first div and the third div vertically. How can I keep the distance between these divs always the same like 50px no matter if show more is clicked or not? I will attach an image if it is confusing.

Comment: I am using bootstrap and it floats all the divs. I am not applying any styling to on any div.

Comment: please add a screenshot; it will help users who like to think visually instead of read a description.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using bootstrap. You need to stick both your first and third divs into the same column, and give them their own columns to fill.

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h1 class="text-info">Headline One</h1>
        <hr />
        <button>Show More</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h1 class="text-info">Headline Two</h1>
        <hr />
        <button>Show More</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <h1 class="text-info">Headline Three</h1>
    <hr />
    <button>Show More</button>
</div>
```

You will notice I also used just `col-xs`. This is because bootstrap column classes scale up from the small. This will have the same layout no matter the screen size. Using `col-lg-6` and `col-md-6` like you were before is redundant. If you wish to change the layout per device size, always remember that `xs` will apply to all, and each larger one will override the smaller ones for the appropriate screen sizes.

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uqu835mc/2/

---

As Jason W mentioned in comments below, you can use `<div class="row">...</div>` on the rows you are making to control the margin and padding of these columns inside a container. Here's how that looks:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <h1 class="text-info">Headline One</h1>
                    <hr />
                    <button>Show More</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <h1 class="text-info">Headline Two</h1>
                    <hr />
                    <button>Show More</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <h1 class="text-info">Headline Three</h1>
            <hr />
            <button>Show More</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle using `row`s: https://jsfiddle.net/uqu835mc/4/

---

*EDIT: to have them all in a column on small screens, use `<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">` for both of the outermost columns like so:*

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <h1 class="text-info">Headline One</h1>
                    <hr />
                    <button>Show More</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <h1 class="text-info">Headline Two</h1>
                    <hr />
                    <button>Show More</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
            <h1 class="text-info">Headline Three</h1>
            <hr />
            <button>Show More</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You might also consider wrapping a "row" (<div class="row">...</div>) around the columns to get the padding right in the container.

Comment: True! Wrapping the `col` divs that you want in a single row with a `<div class="row">` will keep your containers flush with the margin/padding on each of their ends (inside spacing will not be affected).

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks. This markup works nicely on large screens but when the screen is smaller in Size I want headline two below headline One. How can I modify this code to accomplish this?

Comment: use `<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">` for both of the outermost columns. That will make them full screen width on `xs` and `sm` size screens, and half the screen on `md` and `lg` size screens. I included an example of this at the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the bootstrap class `pull-right` on all the divs in the right column then it will do the trick. Here is the html:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <h1 class="text-info">Headline One</h1><hr>
  <button>Show More</button>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 pull-right">
  <h1 class="text-info">Headline Two</h1><hr>
  <button>Show More</button>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <h1 class="text-info">Headline Three</h1><hr>
  <button>Show More</button>
</div>
```

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kg8sh1wp/

**Be sure to wrap the columns in a row like I did in my example or it may ruin the positioning of other dom elements.**

Comment: You don't need "col-lg-6 col-md-6" - the medium covers the large.

Comment: Thanks @MrMadsen This markup works nicely on large screens but when the screen is smaller in Size I want headline two below headline One.  How can I modify this code to accomplish this?

Comment: @SujataHulsurkar I edited my post - try the new fiddle I attached and see if that is what you're looking for.